# Its possible to export VCalendar with only one Event with ruby-iCalendar?

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I add events to iCalendar:

```
require 'icalendar'
calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new
...some properties to calendar
event = Icalendar::Event.new
...some properties to event 1
calendar.add_event(event)
event = Icalendar::Event.new
...some properties to event 2
calendar.add_event(event)
```

When I call to output the whole calendar is published (simplified)

```
calendar.to_ical

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
...event 1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
...event 2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

If I call the output of event 1 only

```
event.to_ical

BEGIN:VEVENT
...event 1
END:VEVENT
```

I want output the VCalendar with only this event (like a filter)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
...event 1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Is there a way with the calendar-object?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'icalendar'
calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new
...some properties to calendar
event = Icalendar::Event.new
...some properties to event 1
calendar.add_event(event)
calendar_as_string = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n#{event.to_ical}\nEND:VCALENDAR"
```

Bit of a hack, but it should sort you... What does calendar.to_ical print? According to the [tests](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/spec/calendar_spec.rb), it looks like it will do what you need.

Comment: That isn't what Im looking for, because there are many properties added to calendar (and timezones).

Comment: I presented two possible solutions -- one's a bit of a hack, the other is from the gem's tests. Which one isn't what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this moment is, to expand the class:

```
class Icalendar::Event
  attr_accessor :vcard
end

ca = Icalendar::Calendar.new
ca.add_timezone blah
...some properties to calendar
cax = Icalendar::Calendar.new
cax.add_timezone blah
...some properties to calendar
event = Icalendar::Event.new
... add some properties to event
cax.add_event(event)
event.vcard= cax.to_ical
ca.add_event(event)

puts ca.find_event(uid).vcard
```

But I think there should be a more elegant way to do this. Thanks